# RavenDb studio kills any browser I have

Tags: c#, ravendb-studio

Has anyone had any problems with the Studio taking up alot of memory and CPU?
First I thought that it worked best with latest firefox, but it will just freeze that after a while as well.

Here is a screenshot of my system Resources. Look at my edge browser. At that time I had one tab in Edge and that was the studio.

The database I was looking at had 5 documents created.

[image]

This happen quite often actually. I usually just restart my browser. 
It happens with Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Explorer.

Is there a setting that I am missing?

Comment: I had same issue around 2 years ago with their studio, had to occasionally kill the tab and reload. Looks like they haven't fixed this one yet.

Comment: 24GB RAM? How big are these documents? What were you doing that grabbed 24GB ? Also, why does *Firefox* use 3GB RAM as well? Do you have anything else open that causes such consumption? This sounds like a runaway condition that keeps allocating objects

Comment: Useless comment on tag description: "The RavenDB Management Studio is a **lightweight** Silverlight client..." *looks at image* Sure.

Comment: Like I said, I have 5 (1kb-ish documents, 10 properties) in my Db.
Firefox is a 32bit application (maxed out at 3Gb, I guess), it is also viewing Ravendb studio.